# npm install of angular throws error: ENOTEMPTY

Tags: angular, npm, angular8

When I execute npm install I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOTEMPTY
npm ERR! syscall rmdir
npm ERR! path /home/vagrant/development/wpp/app-web/wpp.web2/node_modules/npm/node_modules/.debug.DELETE/node_modules
npm ERR! errno -39
npm ERR! ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/home/vagrant/development/wpp/app-web/wpp.web2/node_modules/npm/node_modules/.debug.DELETE/node_modules'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/vagrant/.npm/_logs/2020-10-29T18_38_17_165Z-debug.log
```

What I already tried to resolve this:

- delete node_modules folder
- delete only npm folder inside node_modules
- delete ~/.npm file
- delete package-lock.json
- run npm update
- npm cache clear --force
- npm install --save express body-parser --force (even though I don't know what it does)
- sudo npm install
- various combinations of the above

I'm running npm version 6.14.8 and node version 12.19.0

What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: Do you have a `.npmrc` file in your home directory? Deleting that may help - https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3190#issuecomment-17394391

Comment: it seems like I don't have that file in my home directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was stupid:
The folder was shared with my windows-system and that created some weird side-effect. Using another location solved it.